# Mac App Rejection - Temporary Exception Entitlement Key for Safari

Tags: macos, applescript, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

Let's consider an app doing the following steps using AppleScript, in order to auto-login to some website:

1- Open "Safari" and navigate to website

2- Fill the username and password fields with JavaScript
`do JavaScript " document.getElementById('password_input').value = 'userPassword' "`

3- Submit form using JavaScript     ---     `do JavaScript " document.forms['login_form'].submit() "`

For a sandboxed Mac app, **com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events** entitlement key must be added for "Safari", in order to execute AppleScript procedure above.

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
<string>com.apple.safari</string>
</array>
```

Everything works great this way, without any problem.

Here is my question:

Does the app get rejected because of this temporary exception usage for Safari?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After waiting for more than one month, my app got approved.

In entitlements section of iTunesConnect, I briefly explained why I used this entitlement key, and my app got approved without any problem.

So I can say that temporary exception usage for Safari is **NOT** a reject reason.

Comment: Very genuine problem. I have same doubt and it's clear here. 
Thanks :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it :

https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit/issues/109

In particular see comment from Ishuo

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I don't think it's the same scenario. So just an up-vote.

Comment: This link might be of interest. In particular the paragraph about the temporary exception : http://hamishrickerby.com/page/2/