# How to programmatically focus Desktop/Finder via Mac App?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, desktop, finder

I want to focus Desktop/Finder via my App, especially if the user is currently inside a fullscreen application.
I've been trying to use stuff like:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"Finder"];
```

and

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:nil withApplication:@"Finder"];
```

But using these lines of code, a new Finder window will open "All Files". 
I just want to focus the Desktop/Finder, how can I do that? Looking for App Store-ready code.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems like applescript could be used here...

Comment: I don't think that apple would allow sandboxed apps that play around with Finder using applescript

Comment: no AS needed here.. NSRunningApplication can be activated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can do it using cocoa's NSWorkspace - no special entitlements needed

```
NSArray *apps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];

for (NSRunningApplication *app in apps) {
    if([app.bundleIdentifier.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"com.apple.finder"]) {
        [app activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateAllWindows|NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using applescript, which *should* be possible to use along with a mac store app, after a bit of research and some entitlements entries.

Here's an AppleScript script that will do what you want:

```applescript
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

Entitlements entries:

```xml
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.finder</string>
</array>
```

And you can read more about the entitlements process [here](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/08/the-app-store-sandboxing-and-applescript/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858642/mac-app-rejection-temporary-exception-entitlement-key-for-safari).

I understand this is not a complete answer - I am not a mac expert. I just wanted to try and point you in the correct direction for solving your problem.

Comment: this should work ... but you don't need AS for that.. sec Ill try to do it using cocoa

Answer (score 0):

Swift, using `NSRunningApplication.runningApplications`

```
NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.finder").first?.activate(options: [])
```